# Linking libraries and including headers properly

Tags: c, makefile, linker, include, static-linking

I'm having a lot of trouble putting together my c program.  This particular issue seems to stem from the linker phase of my compilation.  I've spent a lot of time looking at how to do this properly, and I'm out of ideas now.  Hopefully, someone here can tell me what I'm missing or what I've put in the wrong place.

This is the particular error, which occurs after giving the make all command:

```
gcc     readers_writers.c bin/readers_writers   -o readers_writers
readers_writers.c:13:23: fatal error: rtthreads.h: No such file or directory
#include "rtthreads.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'readers_writers' failed
```

Here are the files in my working directory:

```
monitor.h monitor.c readers_writers.c reader_writer_monitor.c   reader_writer_monitor.h Makefile
```

This is the path and file which I need to include.  Its a real-time threads package.

```
/student/cmpt332/rtt/include/rtthreads.h
```

this is the path to the library:

```
/student/cmpt332/rtt/lib/Linuxx86_64/libRtt.a
```

This is the relevant content of my Makefile:

```
119 RW_C = reader_writer_monitor.c readers_writers.c
120 RW_H = reader_writer_monitor.h
121 RW_OBJ = $(OD)reader_writer_monitor.o $(OD)readers_writers.o
122 $(BIN)readers_writers : $(RW_OBJ) $(LL)libmonitor.a
123   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(RTTIC) -o $@ $(RW_OBJ) $(RTTLC) $(MON_LIB)
124 $(OD)reader_writer_monitor.o : reader_writer_monitor.c $(RW_H)
125   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(MON_LIB)
126 $(OD)readers_writers.o : readers_writers.c $(RW_H)
137   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(RTTIC) -o $@ -c $< $(MON_LIB)
```

And $(BIN), $(OD) are:
    ./bin/
    ./obj/

Here are all the variable declarations:

```
34 DIR = /student/cmpt332/
35 RTTDIR = $(DIR)rtt/
36 RTTIC = -I$(RTTDIR)include/
37 RTTLC = -L$(RTTDIR)lib/$(CURR_OS)$(ARCH) -m32 -lRtt
```

From what I've learned ( or what I thought I'd learned, ) the include path $(RTTIC) and the library path $(RTTLC) should be all I need to successfully link the library 'libRtt.a' to my readers-writers program.

I've tried a ton of small variations on the order of where those paths come in my Makefile recipes, but with no success.  I know there's lots of threads in different forums and places all over, but I'm at my wits end now, after a few days of trying to figure this out.  Any help is appreciated.

Makefile, from popular request:

```
 4  # ...
 8  ########################################
 9  # Fancy variable debugging tool
 10 print-%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)
 11 ########################################
 12 # OS and architecture macros
 13 CURR_OS := $(shell uname -s)
 14 ARCH := $(shell uname -m)
 15 MAC_OS = Darwin
 16 LINUX_OS = Linux
 17 WIN_OS = MINGW32_NT-6.1
 18 ########################################
 19 # Select the architecture
 20 ifeq ($(ARCH),x86_64)
 21   BITS=64
 22 else
 23   BITS=32
 24 endif
 25 ########################################
 26 # Check if '-static' can be used?
 27 ifneq ($(CURR_OS), $(MAC_OS))
 28   STATIC = -static
 29 else
 30   STATIC =
 31 endif
 32 #######################################
 33 # THREADS
 34 DIR = /student/cmpt332/
 35 UBCDIR = $(DIR)pthreads/
 36 RTTDIR = $(DIR)rtt/
 37 # RTT THREADS
 38 RTTIC = -I$(RTTDIR)include/
 39 RTTLC = -L$(RTTDIR)lib/$(CURR_OS)$(ARCH) -m32 -lRtt
 40 RTTLCUTILS = -L$(RTTDIR)lib/$(CURR_OS)$(ARCH) -m32 -lRttUtils
 41 # UBC PTHREADS
 42 UBCC = l$(UBCDIR) -m32
 43 UBCL = -L$(UBCDIR)/lib/$(CURR_OS)$(ARCH) -m32 -lpthreads
 44 UBCI = -I$(UBCDIR)
 45
 46 ########################################
 47 BIN = ./bin/
 48 LL = ./lib/$(CURR_OS)$(ARCH)/
 49 OD = ./obj/$(CURR_OS)$(ARCH)/
 50 LIST_LIB = -L$(LL) -llist
 51 MON_LIB = -L$(LL) -lmonitor
 52 ########################################
 53 # Compiler and linker options
 54 CC = gcc
 55 AR_OPTIONS = cr
 56 C_FLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -g -m32
 57 LD_FLAGS = -m32
 58 ########################################
 59 # Recipes
 60 .PHONY: all clean
 61
 62 liblist: $(LL)liblist.a
 63 test_list: $(BIN)my_test_list
 64 libmonitor: $(LL)libmonitor.a
 65 readers_writers: $(BIN)readers_writers
 66 all: builddirs liblist test_list libmonitor readers_writers
 67 ########################################
 68 # build the subdirs for libraries and
 69 # object files
 70 builddirs:
 71     mkdir -p $(LL)
 72     mkdir -p $(OD)
 73     mkdir -p $(BIN)
 74
 75 #=======================================
 76 # LIST LIB
 77 #=======================================
 78 LIST_C = list_adders.c list_movers.c list_removers.c list.c
 79 LIST_H = list.h
 80 LIST_OBJ = $(OD)list_adders.o $(OD)list_movers.o $(OD)list_removers.o $(OD)list.o
 81 # LIST library
 82 $(LL)liblist.a : $(LIST_OBJ)
 83   ar $(AR_OPTIONS) $@ $^
 84 # LIST LIBRARY OBJ FILES
 85 $(OD)list.o : list.c $(LIST_H)
 86   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
 87 $(OD)list_adders.o : list_adders.c $(LIST_H)
 88   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
 89 $(OD)list_movers.o : list_movers.c $(LIST_H)
 90   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
 91 $(OD)list_removers.o : list_removers.c $(LIST_H)
 92   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
 93 #=======================================
 94 # TEST LIST
 95 #=======================================
 96 LIST_TEST_C = my_test_list.c
 97 LIST_TEST_OBJ = $(OD)my_test_list.o
 98 $(BIN)my_test_list : $(LIST_TEST_OBJ) $(LL)liblist.a
 99   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(LIST_TEST_OBJ) $(LIST_LIB) -o $@
100 $(OD)my_test_list.o : $(LIST_TEST_C) $(LIST_H)
101   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
102 #=======================================
103 ...
107 #=======================================
108 MON_C = monitor.c
109 MON_H = monitor.h
110 MON_OBJ = $(OD)monitor.o
111 # MONITOR library
112 $(LL)libmonitor.a : $(MON_OBJ)
113   ar $(AR_OPTIONS) $@ $^
114 $(OD)monitor.o : $(MON_C) $(MON_H)
115   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
116 #=======================================
117 # READERS WRITERS
118 #=======================================
119 RW_C = reader_writer_monitor.c readers_writers.c
120 RW_H = reader_writer_monitor.h
121 RW_OBJ = $(OD)reader_writer_monitor.o $(OD)readers_writers.o
122 # readers_writers
123 $(BIN)readers_writers : $(RW_OBJ) $(LL)libmonitor.a
124   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(RTTIC) -o $@ $(RW_OBJ) $(RTTLC) $(MON_LIB)
125 # reader_writer_monitor.o
126 $(OD)reader_writer_monitor.o : reader_writer_monitor.c $(RW_H)
127   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $< $(MON_LIB)
128 # readers_writers.o
129 $(OD)readers_writers.o : readers_writers.c $(RW_H)
130   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(RTTIC) -o $@ -c $< $(MON_LIB)
```

When I compile without this recipe,

```
122 # readers_writers
123 $(BIN)readers_writers : $(RW_OBJ) $(LL)libmonitor.a
124   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(RTTIC) -o $@ $(RW_OBJ) $(RTTLC) $(MON_LIB)
```

the .o files `readers_writers.o` and `reader_writer_monitor.o` compile just fine.  When I run it the readers_writers recipe like so:

```
22 # readers_writers
123 $(BIN)readers_writers : $(RW_OBJ) $(LL)libmonitor.a
124   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ $(RW_OBJ)
```

I get a whole load of undefined references in both .o files to function in my $(MON_LIB) and the real-time threads library.  When I compile with the recipe like THIS:

```
122 # readers_writers
123 $(BIN)readers_writers : $(RW_OBJ) $(LL)libmonitor.a
124   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) -o $@ $(RW_OBJ) $(MON_LIB) $(RTTIC) $(RTTLC) $(MON_LIB)
```

I get the single fatal error which tells me there is no such file "rtthreads.h"

I'm seriously at a loss, still.

RESOLVED

Okay, finally figured it out!  After switching up my directory variables ( $(OD), $(BIN), etc ) to not include the trailing slash, and making sure my -I and -L directives were in the proper place, I made a couple very small changes which got things compiling properly.

this:

```
65 readers_writers: $(BIN)readers_writers
66 all: builddirs liblist test_list libmonitor readers_writers
```

turned into this:

```
65 ###
66 all: builddirs liblist test_list libmonitor readers_writers
```

and the directive here:

```
123 $(BIN)readers_writers : $(RW_OBJ) $(LL)libmonitor.a
124   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(RTTIC) -o $@ $(RW_OBJ) $(RTTLC) $(MON_LIB)
```

turned into this:

```
123 readers_writers : $(RW_OBJ) $(LL)libmonitor.a
124   $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(RTTIC) -o $@ $(RW_OBJ) $(RTTLC) $(MON_LIB)
```

That was all it took!  There's a lesson in there somewhere.

Comment: Please post the whole makefile

Comment: From what I can tell `RTTIC` and `RTTLC` are still undefined when the line `gcc     readers_writers.c bin/readers_writers   -o readers_writers` is getting executed. You notice that it has no `-I...` or `-L...` attached to it. Maybe try running `make -n` or if that doesn't help `make -np`. In the worst case you could use `make -nd` (I don't remember which SO answer I read these about, but has stuck to my mind).

Comment: You're trying to include a header and link to a library. The first appears to be failing, and you seem to think the second is too. **Try them separately:** try building `readers_writers.o` (no linking), and try linking `HelloWorld` to the library.

Comment: The command which is running is the recipe for `readers_writers`, which is not in the extract of your Makefile; what you show is the recipe for `bin/readers_writers`. The fact that you have two targets called `readers_writers` in different directories strikes me as confusing (but the problem is the specific recipe, not my confusion :) ) As @BenWainwright says, it would be useful to see more (or even all) of the `Makefile`

Comment: @rici The readers_writers/./bin/readers_writers discrepancy I think can be explained by the name of the target on line 65 of the Makefile.  I'm going to try a couple of the suggestions here.

Comment: To get 64 bit or 32 architecture, you can do something like `BITS := $(shell getconf LONG_BIT)`